# Errors in closed question help page

Tags: bug, help-center

#### There are errors on the help page "What does it mean if a question is "closed"?"

An example of this page is https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions.

1. There are two occurrences of the text "See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

   "How to Ask" should be a link to the corresponding help page (example https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

   Please can we linkify the "How to Ask" text?
2. There is one occurrence of the text "Off-topic because…".

   Please can we replace this text with "A community specific reason"

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this later post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353001/335251), which touches on the real issue (several of the quotes from the "Close" dialog were entirely out of date).